# iPhone/iPod Touch sync notifications

Tags: iphone, itunes, notifications, synchronization

I know that it's possible to add an observer for notifications with the `com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo` identifier, but this only seems to include events for music related events.

I also know I can find out when iTunes closes by adding an observer for `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`.

But is there an `NSNotification` for the start/finish of iPhone syncing with iTunes?

Just to be clear, my question is about what happens on a Mac not on an iPhone.

Comment: I assume you are trying to do this in app running on a Mac, not on an iPhone?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I'll edit my question to make it clearer. Thanks.